# Зацикливание вывода spring jpa

Tags: spring, java-ee, spring-boot, jpa, spring-jpa

У меня есть сущность

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String lasName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryUser", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<PhoneBook> phoneBook;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "phone_book")
public class PhoneBook {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UserId")
    private User primaryUser;

    private String name;
    ...
}
```

Но когда я делаю запрашиваю ее (return User), то идет зацикливание и бесконечно выводится User. Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Поставь `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` над `User.phoneBook`.

Comment: Не помогает. Это поле все равно запрашивается

Comment: А если lazy в PhoneBook.primaryUser?

Comment: тоже не работает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

В классе User:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "primaryUser")
    private List<PhoneBook> phoneBook;
```

В классе PhoneBook:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
```